# Git - how do i get which file or code is not exist ONLY IN 1 BRANCH while comparing 2 branch in git?

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to compare of two branch (`master` and `live`) with specific result as below

**Current problem**:

Let say i have 2 `file` in `master`:

- foo.js:

  value inside `foo.js`:

  `console.log('inital foo')`
- bar.js:

  value inside `bar.js`:

  ```
  console.log('bar')
  ```

in `live` branch i have two file:

- `bar.js`

  value inside `bar.js`:

  ```
  //another code that should
  //exist only in live branch
  ...
  console.log('bar')
  ```
- `Constants.js`

  value inside `Constants.js`:

  ```
  BaseURL = 'http://'
  Version = '1.0.1'
  ```

now i want to compare if there's some file/code in `master` **that not exists** in `live` branch

**Current result**:

`git diff live master --name-only` output result:

```
foo.js
bar.js
Constant.js
```

**Expected Result**:

just check in `master` branch any changes/new file that doesn't exists in `live` branch

any command that should outputing result:

```
foo.js
```

**Reason**:

`bar.js` in `live` has another code that should exist only in `live`, and since `master` and `live` has `console.log('bar')`, shouldn't show a result

`Constant.js` should not show as a result since it in `live`

is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this command:

```
git diff live...master --name-only
```

What it does is that it compares changes that occurred on the `master` branch since when the `live` branch was started off it. You can find it in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-Comparingbranches).

Comment: I think `git diff live...master --name-only` solved `Constants.js` to not show in `live`, but how about `bar.js`? +1 anyway :)

Comment: @flix When was `bar.js` added to each branch?

Comment: when pulling from `master` to `live` or created manually, it's a condition for my case, sometime's i need to pull it from `master` (because of code) or just manually changes (e.g changes version number only, so i didn't pull from 'master' and just type manually from `live` branch to match like `master` version number)